# Keras Neural Network training is stuck (gets stuck around epoch 6)

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, jupyter

I have a training dataset with 8000 rows, and I am trying to train a Keras Neural Network on it, using 100 epochs. However, the training process gets stuck around epoch 6 every time, as shown below. I'm not sure if it's because of my computer (8GB RAM Macbook Pro) or because of some inappropriately set parameters for my model. Thanks!

```
    import keras
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense

    classifier = Sequential()

    classifier.add(Dense(activation="relu", input_dim=11, units=6, kernel_initializer="uniform"))

    classifier.add(Dense(activation="relu", units=6, kernel_initializer="uniform"))

    classifier.add(Dense(activation="sigmoid", units=1, kernel_initializer="uniform"))

    classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, nb_epoch = 100)

8000/8000 [==============================] - 3s 348us/step - loss: 0.3890 - acc: 0.8367
Epoch 2/100
8000/8000 [==============================] - 3s 329us/step - loss: 0.3894 - acc: 0.8376
Epoch 3/100
8000/8000 [==============================] - 3s 314us/step - loss: 0.3887 - acc: 0.8370
Epoch 4/100
8000/8000 [==============================] - 3s 346us/step - loss: 0.3895 - acc: 0.8379
Epoch 5/100
8000/8000 [==============================] - 3s 320us/step - loss: 0.3887 - acc: 0.8370 - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.4087 - acc: 0.8077
Epoch 6/100
7650/8000 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3881 - acc: 0.8363 
//STUCK HERE
```

I do get the following message on my terminal window though (even though I'm using jupyter notebook):

`2017-12-24 20:45:30.464660: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.`

Comment: does it stuck or exits the code and shows the message?

Comment: @Media It just gets stuck. The message is shown on terminal as soon as I execute `classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, nb_epoch = 100)`, then it will go up to around epoch 7 and get stuck and my computer fan starts whirring loudly

Comment: I suggest you update your anaconda. I had a similar problem on my windows version of anaconda jupyter notebook. But the keras worked fine in my ubuntu. I updated it on windows and it didn't get stuck.

Comment: @Media Thanks very much, that fixed it! Merry Christmas

Comment: happy christmas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. I guess the reason is incompatibility of `Keras` with your current anaconda. Just update it.